# create new dataframe after summing values per month

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe containing transactions per day over a multiple year period. I would like to convert this df into df_monthly where each row contains the sum of transactions in a given month, arranged from 1 (jan) 2019 to 2 (feb) 2020.

Suppose this is my df:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-01', 11, 82],
                   ['2019--01-02', 3, 98],
                   ['2019-02-01', 1, 3],
                   ['2019-02-02', 47, 79],
                   ['2020-01-01', 56, 48],
                   ['2020-02-02', 8, 2]], columns=['date', 'col1', 'col2'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df

           col1 col2
date        
2019-01-01  11  82
2019-01-02  3   98
2019-02-01  1   3
2019-02-02  47  79
2020-01-01  56  48
2020-02-02  8   2
```

I tried this

```
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df_monthly = df.groupby(['month', 'year']).sum()
```

output:

```
               col1 col2
month   year        
1       2019    14  180
        2020    56  48
2       2019    48  82
        2020    8   2
```

What I would like is this:

```
    year    month   col1 col2
0   2019    1       14   180
1   2019    2       48    82
2   2020    1       56    48
3   2020    2        8     2
```

Do you have suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: I think changing the groupby to `df.groupby(['month', 'year']).sum()` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'groupby' can be used.

```
df.groupby(['year','month']).agg(sum).reset_index()
   
    year    month   col1    col2
0   2019    1   14  180
1   2019    2   48  82
2   2020    1   56  48
3   2020    2   8   2
```

Answer (score 0):

data = df_monthly.reset_index()

print(data.sort_values(by=['year']))

```
   month  year  col1  col2
0      1  2019    14   180
2      2  2019    48    82
1      1  2020    56    48
3      2  2020     8     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a sorting , reset index, rearrange columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-01', 11, 82],
                   ['2019--01-02', 3, 98],
                   ['2019-02-01', 1, 3],
                   ['2019-02-02', 47, 79],
                   ['2020-01-01', 56, 48],
                   ['2020-02-02', 8, 2]], columns=['date', 'col1', 'col2'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
# print(df)
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df_monthly = df.groupby(['month', 'year']).sum()

df_monthly = df_monthly.sort_values(['year']).reset_index()
cols = df_monthly.columns.tolist()
# print(cols)
cols = [cols[1]] + [cols[0]] + cols[2:]
df_monthly = df_monthly[cols]
print(df_monthly)
```

Returning:

```
   year  month  col1  col2
0  2019      1    14   180
1  2019      2    48    82
2  2020      1    56    48
3  2020      2     8     2
```